# Is there any way to get owner ids who have more than 2 books using PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, having

In `libraries` table, there are `owner_id` and `book_id`.

Each `owner` can have only one `book`.
For example,

```
  id|owner_id|book_id
  3 |  2     | 1
  5 |  2     | 1
```

But now some owners have more than 2 books.

```
  id|owner_id|book_id
  9 |  5     | 1
  11|  5     | 2
```

Is there any way to get **owner ids** who have more than **2 books** using **PostgreSQL query**?

Comment: *who have more than 2 books* `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT book_id) > 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select owner_id from librarires group by owner_id having count(*) > 1
```

This assumes that `(book_id, owner_id)` tuples are unique in the table. If duplicate may happen and you want to count only distinct books per owner, then:

```
select owner_id from librarires group by owner_id having count(distinct book_id) > 1
```